# ASP Include file not found

Tags: iis-7, asp-classic

I am a Systems Administrator (not for a company just work for a 3rd party company), and having an issue with an error that i receive on the server side when browsing his website from the server.

> Error
>
> Active Server Pages error 'ASP 0126'
>
> Include file not found
>
> /login.asp, line 3
>
> The include file '/includes/connect.asp' was not found

I enabled parent paths in IIS 7 but it stills errors out.  I am not a ASP guy at all, but all things in IIS looks ok.  Is it his code?  Anything he could try?  Had a feeling doing research that it has something to do with his paths to his file?

Thanks guys

Comment: Probably the website is not on the root. Try asking him to change the line to: `<!-- #include virtual="includes/connect.asp" -->`.

Comment: That depends how you are including the file. Is it absolute or relative path, or there might be directory issues

Answer (score 4):

**You may receive an "ASP 0126" error message when you try to view an ASP Web page that is hosted in IIS 6**

Please check this post from MSDN. Resolutions are there.

[ASP 0126](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/920721)

Just to bring the answer to Stack Overflow. Below are the workarounds.

**Method 1: Use the #include virtual statement together with an absolute file path**

To work around this issue, use the #include virtual statement together with an absolute file path in the Test.asp Web page. Consider the following code examples:
The following line of code does not work.

```
<!-- #include virtual ="../Date.asp" -->
```

The follow line of code works.

```
<!-- #include virtual ="Samples/Includes/Date.asp" -->
```

**Method 2: Use the #include file statement together with a relative file path**

To work around this issue, use the #include file statement together with a relative file path in the Test.asp Web page. Consider the following code samples:
The following line of code does not work.

```
<!-- #include virtual ="../Date.asp" -->
```

The following line of code does work.

```
<!-- #include file ="..\Date.asp -->

Note By default, parent paths are disabled in IIS 6. To enable parent paths, you must manually set the AspEnableParentPaths property in the metabase to TRUE.
```

Comment: Just one doubt-Do we need to give complete path,eg: "c://abc/include/myfile.asp" because i could not see the Drive letter in any of the answers on web